# Process initiated for bulk insert task in SSIS stays in sleeping state

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, database-administration

I have a SSIS package with Bulk insert task that executes couple of times daily.
It came to our observation that a lot of times the process initiated by this task/Package stays in sleeping state for days, however the package either completes or errors out.
I tried to find out the reason for this, however I didn't find anything.
Any help in this is really appreatiated.

Comment: In what way is the package staying in a sleeping state?  what are you observing that makes you say this?

Comment: in sysprocesses, application which executes the package appears with the datetime same as that of the request for the execution of the pakcage

Comment: Ok, then what makes you say the package "completes or errors out"?

Comment: we track the progress of the package to an audit table. this table tell us the time of the execution of the package. Even if the package errors out at or after Bulk Insert task, there will certainly be a process in Sleeping state in sysprocesses.

Comment: I'm sorry there are too many moving pieces and you haven't narrowed the focus of the problem to which part is causing the problem.   I don't think anybody can help you without being able to look at your package and all the code involved in running it.  It could be anything.